# How to produce Ancient Fruits?

Tags: stardew-valley

I heard there was a way to produce Ancient Fruits, which are a kind of fruits that can be sold for a high price. How can you obtain the seeds which enable you to produce those fruits, and is there some particular conditions to make these grow ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to get ancient seeds:

- Donate the Ancient Seed artifact to Gunther at the museum and he will give you a plantable packet as a reward. He'll also give you a crafting recipe to turn any other Ancient Seeds into the plantable version.
- The travelling cart occasionally sells them for 400-700g
- Putting Ancient Fruits into the seed maker will give you seeds (though you need an ancient fruit seed to start your ancient fruit plantation)
- Other plants have a very low chance to give an ancient seed when put in the seed maker

The Ancient Fruit plant is unique in that in grows in all three growing seasons- spring, summer, and fall. It takes a whole month to grow and produces fruit every 7 days, so it is best to plant it at the start of spring or in a greenhouse.

Answer (score 1):

Ancient fruits grow from ancient seeds, which can be crafted from ancient seeds. Confused yet?

One of the artifacts that can be found in the mine is the ancient seed, which looks like a small bead. Donating one to the museum unlocks a crafting recipe to turn the artifact ancient seed into a plantable packet of ancient seeds.

Ancient plants take 28 days to mature, and regrow every 8 days. They grow in spring, summer and winter.

Comment: It is indeed confusing at first sight. Thank you for the answer !

Answer (score -3):

As said previously the wandering merchant and Gunter, through the donation of the ancient seed, are both ways to do it. In my experience however the difficulty in getting ancient seeds through the seed maker is far over stated. I have put in 9 potatoes and 8 out of those 9 have given me ancient fruit seeds.

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your experience doesn't make it any easier for everyone else to get Ancient Fruit Seeds.

Comment: And given that all your really saying is "that other users answer worked for me", this should really be an upvote and a comment.

Comment: The chance of that happening is less than one in two quintillion, so I'm afraid I don't believe you unless you have mods that change it.